# Norm of $Tf(x)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(x-y)f(y)\,dy$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I'm dealing with this operator $T\in \mathcal{L}(H)$ where $H=L^2([-\pi,\pi])$
$$
Tf(x) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(x-y)f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
One of the questions request to compute the norm of the operator. I tried but only show that
$$
\|Tf\|\leq \sqrt{2}\pi \|f\|
$$
with Cauchy-Schwarz. I already show that this operator is compact and self-adjoint hence
$$
\|T\| = \rho(T) = \sup_{\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)}|\lambda|
$$
Since $\sigma(T)=\{0,\pi\}$, then $\|T\|=\pi$. I want to get the same result by definition of norm but I can't find another bound. Does anyone have any suggestion for compute the norm?

Comment: What does the notation $\mathcal{L}([-\pi,\pi])$ mean? $[-\pi,\pi]$ is not a function space, is the space understood to be something?

Comment: Of course the lower limit on integral should be $-\pi$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I already corrected

Comment: @matdlara You might find [Young's convolution inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality) to be helpful

Comment: @BenGrossmann The Young inequality would give the optimal result if the operator was a convolution with nonnegative function.

Comment: The operator $T$ is a convolution. By the Fourier transform it is unitarily equivalent to the multiplication operator by the function $\pi(\delta_{-1}+\delta_1)$ on the space $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}).$ Obviously the norm of this operator is  equal $\pi.$ By the way   $\sigma(T)=\{0,-\pi,\pi\}.$

Comment: @matdlara Are you sure that it's $\sqrt{2}\pi$ and not $\sqrt{2\pi}$?

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
      Tf = \langle f,\cos\rangle\cos +\langle f\sin\rangle\sin
$$
where $\langle g,h\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(x)h(x)dx$ if your space is a real space, and where $\langle g,h\rangle=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(x)\overline{h(x)}dx$ if your space is complex. Whether the space is complex or real, $\|\sin\|=\sqrt{\pi}$ and $\|\cos\|=\sqrt{\pi}$, and $\{ \frac{\sin}{\sqrt{\pi}},\frac{\cos}{\sqrt{\pi}}\}$ is an orthonormal subject of $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$; and $Tf$ is a constant multiple (the multiple is $\sqrt{\pi}$) of the orthonormal projection of $f$ onto the subspace spanned by $\{\cos(x),\sin(x)\}$. So the spectrum of $T$ is $\{ 0, \sqrt{\pi}\}$. The norm of $T$ is $\sqrt{\pi}$.